# ISPConfig - two phpmyadmin versions

Tags: phpmyadmin

I've installed `phpmyadmin` first and then I configured ISPConfig, which appears to come with a different `phpmyadmin` version (an older one). How do I run only one of them?

EDIT: whenever I go to my server's FQDN (server.domain.com/phpmyadmin) I see the newer version. But once I enter one of my domains which I created under the `Sites` section in ISPConfig (mydomain.com/phpmyadmin) I see the older version.

EDIT2: The version appears to be the same: 3.4.11.1deb2+deb7u1. However, the user interface is a bit different. Why is that?

Comment: You need to properly configure your webserver...

Comment: I'm sorry, but your comment is completely pointless.

Comment: A proper configuration would lead to only using a single instance of `phpmyadmin`, after which you could probably remove the other instance. But if you know better, why do you ask this question?

Comment: I don't, that's why I'm asking. Now clearly I understand that there is something wrong with my setup, therefore your first comment adds absolutely nothing valuable to the issue. Would you care to share some insights? Where should I begin?

Comment: I've edited my question. The versions appear to be the same, but the UI is a bit different.